# How to identify memory consuming requests in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, memory, multithreading

The IIS http log tells me the time taken, so it's easy to identify long-running requests. But how can I identify the memory consumption of each request thread?

From within the process code I can easily get the size of the workingset for the entire process, but not of a request thread itself.

IIS 6 + Framework 3.5

Nick

Answer (score 1):

You could use a memory profiler such as the [ANTS Memory Profiler from RedGate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/index_v2.htm) (14-free trial).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I'm reading you correctly but the threads are reused so there's no such thing as one thread per request. There's still hope, for instance you could set up a performance monitor log. [Tess Ferrandez](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/about.aspx) has quite a few [articles](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2007/08/13/asp-net-memory-investigation.aspx) on [.NET memory debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/02/15/net-debugging-demos-lab-3-memory.aspx).

Or if you really want to dive in:

1. adplus -hang -pn w3wp.exe -quiet
2. Open the dump file in windbg
3. !address -summary

Comment: Thanks Jonas, your's is the only sensible response so far, others don't actually seem to understand the question. And even you weren't sure, so I'll rephrase it in a new question.

Comment: I must also try your diving suggestion, though I don't think it's going to provide me with what I'm seeking.